# How to open data in pop up using bootstrap model in datatables

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

Here, I am trying to populate data from db in a popup box.

I am using datatables in Django template and rendering data.

Now I want a view button on my page and the button should open a popup box corresponding to the row.

I have gone through datatable documentation - https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap4-modal.html
where we can populate the data but here problem is, how can we get data from server or how can we process data from server for popup box.

Any solution?

Could you please suggest solutions?

```
 <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <table id="service_center" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Vehical</th>
                                    <th>Service Date</th>
                                    <th>KMS</th>
                                    <th>View</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/plugins/datatables/dataTables.editor.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/plugins/datatables/editor.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: '_all',
                        defaultContent: ''
                    }
                ]
            });
            var table = $('#service_center').DataTable({
                "pageLength": 100,
                "serverSide": true,
                "bSearchable":true,
                "dom": 'blfrtip',
                "ajax": "/dt/veh_service/?format=datatables",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "m.veh_number"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "service_date"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "kms"
                    },{
                    "data": "id",
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary" href="/veh_service/' + full.id + '/edit">' + 'View' + '</a>';
                    }
                }]
            });

            $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var triggerLink = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var id = triggerLink.data("id");
    var title = triggerLink.data("title");
    var cover_small = triggerLink.data("cover_small");

    $("#modalTitle").text(title);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").html("<h5>id: "+id+"</h5><img src='"+cover_small+"'/>");
    });


        });
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: First, you need to replace the anchor link by a # or replace it by a button with data-target ...! I assume you already have a hidden modal with a specific id. Then if you expect your modal body to be your editor. Put a form within using classnames for each input appropriate to it's data you are getting from the table... then inside the same jQuery scope showing your modal, you update those inputs values using same class names... I started a fiddle but you are not making things easier for us by sharing just a small piece of  code :)

Comment: Actually, I have a form.py consisting of the fields, I wanted to display. And respective function view in views.py to add and edit the form. In this problem, I am getting data using Django rest framework and displaying using datatables. There in datatables I have to implement the display button to display all row data in a popup box.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a class then create a listener for it.

```
table.on('click', '.btn-class', function() {
    const rowData = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
});
```

This will give you the data for the selected row.

Comment: could you please elaborate you answer bit more? that will be a great help

Comment: I want to open the popup like this - "https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap4-modal.html" but I am not getting the data.